# jQuery: Anything Slider - Multiple Sliders with different CSS styles

Tags: jquery, css, anythingslider

I'm trying to utilize 3 instances of Anything Slider on one page, but I'm having problems styling each slider differently from the other.

The sliders have id's: slider1, slider2, and slider3

So when I try to style a section of slider2 differently, like:

```
#slider2 .anythingSlider-default.activeSlider .anythingWindow {}
```

it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance for the time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I answered your question sufficiently over in the [csstricks forums](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/18322/multiple-anything-slider-styling-on-one-page). Here is it again for completeness:

> Current versions of AnythingSlider have a `theme` option which allows
>   you to change the style for each slider on a page. Then for the css,
>   just add that theme name to the outer wrapper:
>
> ```
> .anythingSlider-theme1 {}
> .anythingSlider-theme1.activeSlider {}
> .anythingSlider-theme1.activeSlider .anythingWindow {}
> .anythingSlider-theme2 {}
> .anythingSlider-theme2.activeSlider {}
> ```
>
> etc...
>
> You can't target the `#slider2` ID because it is inside of `.anythingWindow`